# Connecting drawing images next to each other underneithe Top Canvas Layer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi Im new to Javascript and HTML ive been working with it for 3 months now as an Intern in a web development company. I have decided to undertake a personal project to try and increase my Skills as well as help out a community I am part of.

Essentially I am making an intractable Galactic map that will allow people to place and name systems on this map that they use within their stories. The aim is to create a single place for the community I am part to place their claims. What I want help with is when the user clicks on the canvas they will be taken to a "sector view where they will be able to click again and place their system.

What I need help with is that each sector ajoins the others and should show claims of the ajoining sector if you are close enough to see so. how can i do this currently what i have in mind would not allow me to do so.

Here is an image of what I currently have built of my site : [Website Screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img199/6213/5tvq.png)

this is the first time I am trying to do something like this so im finding it a little hard to explain what I need. If you need any more information ill try and answer as best as possible.

**Brainwave**: Okay so i had the thought of using a bit of maths to check for any claims within a radius of a clicks coordinates. Could anyone point me in the right direction to go about this? and what are some good tips on keeping it from becoming a monster.

Comment: Do I understand that you want to click on one of the grid cells in your example image and then zoom into a more detailed image of that particular grid cell?  If so, do you have zoomed images for each individual grid cell?

Comment: I do i have an image that is meant to represent the sector view. As it stands atm i get the cords from the canvas and will be using that position to draw something onto the top level image later on but right now i want it so that if i click near a place i clicked and placed something that it will show that other thing i placed in the sector view. if you get what i mean?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand :\   So when you click on the top canvas, what do you want to happen?

Comment: When i click the top canvas it should take me to the sector image which is fine (ive got that working but what i want is to be able to show other peoples claims when i click near other claims people have put down. Atm each coordinate i click on creates a sector view but if i was to click the next coordinate along it wouldnt show the the other existing claims.

Comment: Brain wave i need a function that checks for claims within a certain radius of the click and draws them on the canvas where they should be.

Comment: I think I've got it: A click causes surrounding claims to become visible.  If you do another click then the visible claims become invisible and a new set of claims surrounding the new click become visible.

Comment: Yes something like that essentially i want to show all the claims that might be visible within a radius of that click coordinate so say i click on coordinate 345,562 i want to be able to show all claims within several hundred pixels of that click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test whether a circular “claim” is inside a click “search radius” with this math:

```
var dx=mouseX-claimX;
var dy=mouseY-claimY;
if(dx*dx+dy*dy < searchRadius*searchRadius – claimRadius*claimRadius){
    console.log(“This claim is within the search radius”);
}
```

This is one example of how to use this math to reveal claims within the user's search radius

The left canvas is the user doing a search and revealing only those claims in the search radius.

The right canvas shows all the claims.

[image]

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4MY6z/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: black; padding:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var reveal=document.getElementById("reveal");
    var revealCtx=reveal.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;


    var claims=[];
    var searchRadius=50;
    var searchRadius2=searchRadius*searchRadius;

    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
        var x=parseInt(Math.random()*350);
        var y=parseInt(Math.random()*250);
        var radius=parseInt(Math.random()*10+10);
        var color=randomColor();
        claims.push({
            x:x,
            y:y,
            radius:radius,
            color:color
        });

        revealCtx.beginPath();
        revealCtx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        revealCtx.fillStyle=color;
        revealCtx.fill();
        revealCtx.stroke();

    }


    // create a random color object {red,green,blue}
    function randomColor(){
        return("#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    }


    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      for(var i=0;i<claims.length;i++){
          var claim=claims[i];
          var dx=mouseX-claim.x;
          var dy=mouseY-claim.y;
          var rr=claim.radius*claim.radius;
          if(dx*dx+dy*dy<searchRadius2-rr){
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(claim.x,claim.y,claim.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fillStyle=claim.color;
              ctx.fill();
              ctx.stroke();
          }
      }
      // draw sighting scope
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,searchRadius,Math.PI*2,false);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.moveTo(mouseX-searchRadius,mouseY);
      ctx.lineTo(mouseX+searchRadius,mouseY);
      ctx.moveTo(mouseX,mouseY-searchRadius);
      ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY+searchRadius);
      ctx.fillStyle="white";
      ctx.globalAlpha=.40;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=250></canvas>
    <canvas id="reveal" width=350 height=250></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sir are an angel! Id vote this up if I had the rep to do it thanks ill start implementing this and comment back letting you know how i get on.

Comment: Cool! BTW, you have an interesting sounding internship. My internship was preparing tax returns at an accounting office--not nearly as interesting.

Comment: Ha Ha this is a personal project but i was really lucky with this Intern-ship its a small web dev company so ive basically been thrown in the deep end but that's how i learn best :)

Comment: Just note that if less than "half" the claim circle is within the radius it won't be considered inside with this approach which may or may not be correct.

Comment: +1 Yep.  Since I had no exact specs, I just did what I though would look better on the demo :D